# How to define an abstract Graph class for holding any type of data in its nodes?

Tags: c++, graph

I need to define an abstract base class in C++, which can hold any type of data in its nodes.  I'll extend the functionality in derived classes, where I'll specify what kind of representation to hold (Matrix or List).

For ex:

```
template<class T>
class Graph  // <---- This is the abstract base class
{
public:
    virtual void addEdge(u32 src, u32 dest, T value) = 0 override;
    virtual void display() = 0 override;
    virtual unsigned int getVertices() = 0 const override;
    Graph() { };
    virtual ~Graph() { };
};
template<class T>
class AdjListGraph::public Graph 
{
     //This is the derived class representing graph as a adj list
}
    template<class T>
class AdjListMatrix::public Graph
{
     //This is the derived class representing graph as a adj matrix
}
```

Finally I want to use it as below :

```
Graph<char> *g = new AdjListGraph<char>(10);
g->addEdge(0,1,'c');
Graph<int> *g = new AdjListMatrix<int>(10);
g->addEdge(0,1,100);
```

The problem I'm having is when inheriting the classes. Since the base class is a template, I'm expected to specify the type of class when inheriting it.  But this would involve re-writing the same code for multiple types of data. And further if I've custom objects to be stored in the graph, it would be too tedious to expect a specialization of each type.

Is there any way to get around this limitation do what I intend to do ?

Answer (score 0):

> Since the base class is a template, I'm expected to specify the type of class when inheriting it.

It is the same type as the type parameter for the inheriting template.

```
template<class T>
class AdjListGraph : public Graph<T> 
{

};
```